# Best practice for loading external stylesheets and other resources in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When loading style sheets in Vue, what is considered the best practice for load location?

Specifically, should code or style sheets be loaded in the components that use that resource? Or is it recommended to load the resource in the parent page/containing component?

For example, let's say we have a single legacy js script called `baz.js` that must be used by component `Foo`. The parent of component Foo is called `Profile` (the profile page for a user). Now would it be better to load `baz.js` in `Profile` or should it be loaded in `Foo` ?

I have seen others use both approaches but I am not sure what the benefits would be to either approach and which one to use in a given scenario. Is there a single "right" approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question is an opinion-based one so deciding which approach is better is a bit complicated. But for making a decision you can consider some notes.

### Common cases

- If you are using a lazy load for loading your child components within your parent ones, it is better to import your assets right in the exact component that using those assets. You may ask why? Because Webpack will chunk them into separate bundles, so the assets will only load when the child component gets loaded. So if during code-splitting process user did not reach the specific part of the page where the child component exists, the assets won't load either. It may boost app performance in some cases.
- On the other hand, let's say you do not use lazy loading and don't care about it at all, then it doesn't matter where you importing your assets because whenever the parent component gets loaded the children will load with it in the first place. So it won't make any difference where you import your assets.

### General tip

We do not need to use Code splitting and lazy loading always in every single application that we working on, it is good but not necessary. So When you are working on a medium to large scale apps you may consider using these methods where they will enhance the app performance.